# Update oracle table not responding

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, updates

I try to update a table from Sql Developper with the request:

```
update CSTM_T  set TEN='new text' where  DKEY=<key>;
```

But when I launch this request, SQL Developper starts running the request and keeps running.

When I do

```
select * FROM CSTM_T  where  DKEY=<key>;
```

it's working and it's fast.

The same update from my java application has the same problem.
It was working before and the updates on other tables are working well.

Thans for your help,

Comment: Maybe something in that table is locked? This can happen when another transaction is updating and hasn't yet completed the transaction with a commit or rollback. Take a look at what sessions are open in the DB and see if you can drill down to find a session that's holding locks.

Comment: Yes it was that. Thanks